# Determine if relationship exists in Laravel query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've inherited a Laravel 5 project at work and would like to know how I should check for the existence of a related model to avoid null exceptions.

**BlockDate model**

```
class BlockDate extends Model {
    public function claims()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

**User model**

```
class User extends Model {
    public function blocks()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany(BlockDate::class);
    }
}
```

**Pivot table**

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');


$table->unsignedInteger(block_date_id');
$table->foreign('block_date_id')->references('id')->on(block_dates);
```

Users can claim a range of dates for vacation requests. However, users may have no claims or dates may not have been claimed. I am currently using

```
if ($user->blocks->count() > 0) {
    $dates = $user->blocks->sortByDesc('created_at');
    // more logic here....
}
```

I do not like using count everywhere, is there a way to incorporate the check like:

```
// I don't know what hasClaimedDates might be
$dates = $user->hasClaimedDates()->blocks->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel offers an [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional) helper method to guard against nulls:

```
// will return either a collection or null
$dates = optional($user->blocks)->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the actual relationship method instead of the magic accessor:

```
$sortedDates = $user->blocks()->latest()->get();
```

This will give you an empty collection if no relations are established, but it will not fail on the sorting.

Note: `latest()` is an equivalent for `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` in this case.

---

By the way, if you use `$user->blocks->count()`, it will first load all related models into memory and then count on the relation. If you are going to use the related models afterwards, that is fine. But if you don't and you only count them, this is a waste of resources. In this case `$user->blocks()->count()` is way more performant as it executes a database query that only returns a single number. Take this into consideration especially where you have a lot of related models.